# How to get the process ID in a Browser Helper Object's code?

Tags: windows, internet-explorer, winapi, bho

I want to debug my BHO (browser helper object) code. For that, I want to know the process ID of the current process running in the browser. I want to display that process ID with a message box. Please suggest a way for me to do this.

Comment: Use the [GetProcessId function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683215(v=vs.85).aspx) maybe?

Comment: @Melebius - Browser Helper Object is a plugin type on Internet Explorer.    I'll retag the question to Windows instead of C++.

Comment: Are you after the process id of the code executing your helper? If not, how do you propose to identify the other process. The browser can be implemented in multiple processes.

Answer (score 1):

BHO - this is dll which loaded in `iexplore.exe` - so you need simply call [`GetCurrentProcessId();`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683180(v=vs.85).aspx). also of course can be several instances of `iexplore.exe` - and in every `iexplore.exe` will be self BHO dll. for debugging purpose i be advice you set `TabProcGrowth` under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main` and `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main` to 0